# Android programming help

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I'm working on an app where i have textview's in one layout and a button that sends you to a second layout with Edittext's. Every edittext is for an textview. How can i replace text in a textview with the text in edittext with a button in the second layout?

Comment: In the first layout i have a textview and a button. That button sends me to a second layout where i have an edittext and a button. When you type something in the edittext and click the button it should replace the text in textview with the text in edittext.

Comment: i think u've already post the same Question :)

Comment: if u find any answer right plz tick it otherwise you may ask doubts.

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6094598/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 1):

you mean like this ??

in the method onCreate() :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytxtView);
editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myeditText);
```

and then , ovverride the onClick method like this :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v ) {
txtView.setText(editText.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a variable for the textview to access it like

```
Textview txt = (Textview) finviewByid........;
```

implement the following code on button click listener

```
txt.setText(edittext.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textview textview = (textview)findViewById(R.layout.nameoftextview);
edittext edittext = (edittext)findViewById(R.layout.nameofedittext);
textview.settext(edittext.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have to pass the edittext value to the first activity through intent.

Eg:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
i.putExtra("edittext_value", edittext.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Then inside your first activity, you will have to fetch this data as:

```
String value;
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
     value = extras.getString("edittext_value");
     textview.setText(value);
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you want your second activity (let's call it Activity2) to pass text back to the first one (Activity1). To do that, you have to (some code comes from :

Change the way you open Activity2 to

```
Intent EditIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    //Other stuff you may want to do with intent
startActivityForResult(EditIntent , 0);
```

Add override to you Activity1

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
        if (data.hasExtra("myText")) {
            //get your data with data.getExtras().getString("myText")
        }
    }
}
```

Change what button on your Activity2 does

```
{  
    Intent returnData= new Intent();
    returnData.putExtra("myText", /*Text from your EditText*/);
    if (getParent() == null) { //This part was taken from StackOverflow by Ilya Taranov
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnData);
    } else {
        getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnData);
    }
    finish();
}
```

This should return text from EditText from Activity2 to Activity1. Code was not tested