# Android text from edittext to textview

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

In the first layout i have a textview and a button. That button sends me to a second layout where i have an edittext and a button. How can text from the textview be replaced with the text from the edittext when you click the button in the second layout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android programming help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094598/android-programming-help)